How to handle failed Rails ActiveJob after max attemps reached?
I'm looking for a way to handle Rails ActiveJob jobs that reached the max retry attempts.
Here is the snippet of my code:
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  retry_on StandardError, wait: :polynomially_longer, attempts: 3

  def perform(args)
    # Do things here
  end
end

In my case, the job tries a couple of things, including connecting to 3rd party APIs. It happens that the API is not available for a couple of times and the max attempts is reached.
In that case, I want to catch this case and perform some additional logic like updating User records and notifying our team.
I'm using SolidQueue, and was thinking about getting the executions count argument, but again, I need to identify the moment the job has definitely failed.
Any idea of robust a solution to this? It looks like I'm looking for a Dead Letter Queue system.

Hey, is this documentation helpful? https://github.com/rails/solid_queue?tab=readme-ov-file#failed-jobs-and-retries

@zaphodbln_ thanks for the comment. Yes, using SolidQueue to get number of retries is valid. However I found a solution that didn't involve query SolidQueue and is native to ActiveJob. Appreciate your help.

Other responses and comments are valid solutions. I ended up implementing the following feature from ActiveJob:
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  retry_on StandardError, wait: :polynomially_longer, attempts: 3 do |job, error|
    fallback(*job.arguments)
  end

  def perform(args)
    # Do things here
  end

  def fallback(args)
    # This will only be executed once, when the max retries is reached
  end
end

The *job.arguments will ensure the fallback method will get the exact same arguments as the perform method, with the same order.
I got the inspiration from the examples of retry_on of the Rails doc: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on
Hope it will help someone.

These are just my solution from brainstorm, there are 2 options I think that is possible to handle this:
Note: Avoid passing the whole object to a queue, pass only id instead and load the object in the job

Retry on your own

a. if any failed due to API available, consider that flag always true for later retry
class UserJob < ApplicationJob
  MAX_RETRY = 3

  def perform(user_id, api_available: true, current_retry: 0)
    # Your job logic here

    # If API failed once, api_available flag will always false, depend on your demand, you can change this logic
  rescue FailedByAPINotAvailableError
    additional_action if current_retry == MAX_RETRY

    self.class.perform_later(user_id, api_available: false, current_retry: current_retry.next) if current_retry < MAX_RETRY
  rescue StandardError
    self.class.perform_later(user_id, api_available: api_available, current_retry: current_retry.next) if current_retry < MAX_RETRY
  end

  def additional_action
  end
end

b. Only check if api failed for the last retry at MAX_RETRY
class UserJob < ApplicationJob
  MAX_RETRY = 3

  def perform(user_id, current_retry: 0)
    # Your job logic here
  rescue FailedByAPINotAvailableError
    additional_action if current_retry == MAX_RETRY

    self.class.perform_later(user_id, current_retry: current_retry.next) if current_retry < MAX_RETRY
  rescue StandardError
    self.class.perform_later(user_id, current_retry: current_retry.next) if current_retry < MAX_RETRY
  end

  def additional_action
  end
end


Create a table to store job_data, each job normally will have a record in database, the table will have 2 columns: id and data(use serializer to parse the data from yml or json). Then pass the job_data_id to the job to track latest state of the job and update accordingly


Thanks @daxanhkun, this is valid indeed. However I found a solution that is native to ActiveJob and doesn't involve charging the perform method with retries count. Appreciate your help.
